# Finding lists of elements within a string using Pyparsing

Tags: python, parsing, string-parsing, pyparsing

I'm trying to solve the following problem using Pyparsing:
I want to search a string for occurrences of three types of elements:

1. lowercase words
2. lowercase words following the literal string "OBJ"
3. lists containing one of these elements, separated by ','

An example string could be "foo bar OBJ baz foo,bar

I want to process each of these elements in its own parse action.

Here is my code:

```
import pyparsing
from pyparsing import Word, Literal, alphas

def found_word(s, l, t):
    print('word')
def found_obj(s, l, t):
    print('obj')
def found_list(s, l, t):
    print('list')

def process(string):

    word = ~Literal('OBJ ') + Word(alphas.lower())
    word.setParseAction(lambda s,l,t: found_word(s, l, t))
    obj = Literal('OBJ ') +  Word(alphas.lower())
    obj.setParseAction(lambda s,l,t: found_obj(s, l, t))
    item = word | obj
    list = pyparsing.delimitedList(item, delim=',')
    list.setParseAction(lambda s,l,t: found_list(s, l, t))
    element = word | obj | list

    parser = pyparsing.OneOrMore(element)
    parser.searchString(string).pprint()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process('foo bar OBJ baz foo,bar')
```

**Edit:** I've put some test output inside the parseActions just to see if they are getting called. 
The desired output would be:

```
word
word
obj
word
word
list
```

The actual output is:

```
word
word
obj
word
word
```

I.e. the parseAction for the list is not called. How do I need to change my code in order to achieve this?

**Update**
The delimitedList isn't working as I expected. When I call

```
pyparsing.OneOrMore(list).searchString('foo,bar baz')
```

`found_list` seems to be called twice, although there is only one list element in my string:

```
word
word
list
word
list
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your `list` is not being parsed lies in this expression:

```
element = word | obj | list
```

Because you are checking for `word` before `list` (which is a really awful
variable name when working in Python, btw), then the leading "foo" in 
"foo,bar" is being processed as a `word`, since '|' is an eager operator,
matching on the first matching expression.

You can fix this by changing the order of expressions in `element`:

```
element = list | word | obj
```

Or by using '^' instead of '|'. '^' is a patient operator - it evaluates
all of the alternative expressions and selects the longest match.

```
element = word ^ obj ^ list
```

With either of these changes, your output now becomes:

```
word
list
word
list
obj
word
word
list
```

Why all the list matching? Because `delimitedList` will match a single item:

```
>>> wd = Word(alphas)
>>> wdlist = delimitedList(wd)
>>> print(wdlist.parseString('xyz'))
['xyz']
```

If you want to enforce that lists must have > 1 item, then you can add a
condition parse action:

```
>>> wdlist.addCondition(lambda t: len(t)>1)
>>> print(wdlist.parseString('xyz')) 
... raises exception ...
```

Also, delimitedLists do not automatically group their results:

```
>>> print((wd + wdlist).parseString('xyz abc,def'))
['xyz', 'abc', 'def']
```

If you want to keep the list contents as a list in the results, then wrap 
the list expression in a Group:

```
>>> print((wd + Group(wdlist)).parseString('xyz abc,def'))
['xyz', ['abc', 'def']]
```

Here is my updated version of your `process()` method:

```
def process(string):
    print(string)

    word = ~Literal('OBJ') + Word(alphas.lower())
    word.addParseAction(lambda s,l,t: found_word(s, l, t))
    word.setName("word")
    obj = Literal('OBJ') +  Word(alphas.lower())
    obj.setName("obj")
    obj.addParseAction(lambda s,l,t: found_obj(s, l, t))
    item = word | obj
    list = Group(pyparsing.delimitedList(item, delim=',')
                    .addCondition(lambda t: len(t)>1))
    list.setName("list")
    list.addParseAction(lambda s,l,t: found_list(s, l, t))
    element = obj | list | word

    parser = pyparsing.OneOrMore(element)
    parser.searchString(string).pprint()
```

Which gives this output:

```
foo bar OBJ baz foo,bar
word
word
word
word
obj
word
word
list
[['foo', 'bar', 'OBJ', 'baz', ['foo', 'bar']]]
```

You'll note that I added `setName()` calls for each of your expressions. That
is so that I could add `setDebug()` to get pyparsing's debug output. By adding:

```
word.setDebug()
obj.setDebug()
list.setDebug()
```

before calling `parseString`, you get this debugging output. It may help explain
why you are getting the replicated "word"s in your sample output.

```
foo bar OBJ baz foo,bar
Match obj at loc 0(1,1)
Exception raised:Expected "OBJ", found 'f'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match list at loc 0(1,1)
Match word at loc 0(1,1)
word
Matched word -> ['foo']
Exception raised:failed user-defined condition, found 'f'  (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
Match word at loc 0(1,1)
word
Matched word -> ['foo']
Match obj at loc 3(1,4)
Exception raised:Expected "OBJ", found 'b'  (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)
Match list at loc 3(1,4)
Match word at loc 4(1,5)
word
Matched word -> ['bar']
Exception raised:failed user-defined condition, found 'b'  (at char 4), (line:1, col:5)
Match word at loc 3(1,4)
word
Matched word -> ['bar']
Match obj at loc 7(1,8)
obj
Matched obj -> ['OBJ', 'baz']
Match obj at loc 15(1,16)
Exception raised:Expected "OBJ", found 'f'  (at char 16), (line:1, col:17)
Match list at loc 15(1,16)
Match word at loc 16(1,17)
word
Matched word -> ['foo']
Match word at loc 20(1,21)
word
Matched word -> ['bar']
list
Matched list -> [['foo', 'bar']]
Match obj at loc 23(1,24)
Exception raised:Expected "OBJ", found end of text  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
Match list at loc 23(1,24)
Match word at loc 23(1,24)
Exception raised:Expected W:(abcd...), found end of text  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
Match obj at loc 23(1,24)
Exception raised:Expected "OBJ", found end of text  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
Exception raised:Expected {word | obj}, found end of text  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
Match word at loc 23(1,24)
Exception raised:Expected W:(abcd...), found end of text  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
Match obj at loc 23(1,24)
Exception raised:Expected "OBJ", found end of text  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
Match list at loc 23(1,24)
Match word at loc 23(1,24)
Exception raised:Expected W:(abcd...), found end of text  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
Match obj at loc 23(1,24)
Exception raised:Expected "OBJ", found end of text  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
Exception raised:Expected {word | obj}, found end of text  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
Match word at loc 23(1,24)
Exception raised:Expected W:(abcd...), found end of text  (at char 23), (line:1, col:24)
[['foo', 'bar', 'OBJ', 'baz', ['foo', 'bar']]]
```

Comment: delimitedList now takes min and max arguments also, so a list of 2 or more would done by passing min=2 in the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
s = 'foo bar OBJ baz foo,bar'


for w in s.split(' '):
  if w.islower():
    print("word")
  if 'OBJ' in w:
    print("obj")
  if ',' in w:
    print('list')
```

Comment: I 've used the `split()` to make a list with the string. After, I used a group of conditions to  test each item of the list. To me,  I got  the output desired!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This way I don't get the elements grouped together like specified in the question. Also, separating the elements with split(' ') doesn't work if there is 'OBJ foo' inside the list.